# What is this statement doing in R code?

Tags: r

I know nothing about R, when I read a R code, in the very first line, there appears

```
rm(list=ls())
```

What does it mean?  Thanks

Comment: Almost any function call will have a help file. You should be able to figure out what this statement does by doing `?ls` and `?rm`. Andriyev's response below is correct, incidentally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ls()` in R lists the active variables and `rm(list=ls())` will remove all the active variables.

Comment: @serina you could say as well, that `rm (list = ls())` will remove all the objects in the current environment. it is a `kill all` command. so be a bit careful with it. btw, just read the nicely written R help files, in this case `?rm` and `?ls`

Comment: Cool things like this can also be done: `rm(list=ls(pattern='^a.+'))`

Comment: Vince, thanks for stressing that one, you can use partial matching `ls(pat = "<someregexp>")`, mropa, actually, `rm(list=ls())` doesn't delete ALL object in .GlobalEnv, but only the visible ones. Objects with .Names are omitted. If you want to delete all objects, run `rm(list = ls(all.names = TRUE))`.